# Using a Case statement for an alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to change the header of a column based on a variable

Currently I have

```
SELECT
    (CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(CASE @@Role 
                         WHEN 2 THEN Processor 
                         WHEN 3 THEN Reviewer 
                      END) = 1 
           THEN 'Total' 
           ELSE (CASE @@Role 
                    WHEN 2 THEN Processor 
                    WHEN 3 THEN Reviewer 
                 END) 
     END) AS 'User',
    COUNT(EntityId) AS 'Tickets Processed'
FROM
    table
WHERE
    conditions
GROUP BY
    CASE @@Role 
       WHEN 2 THEN Processor 
       WHEN 3 THEN Reviewer 
    END WITH ROLLUP
```

Right now this returns the data I need for the correct role, however is there a way to change the second column's header based on the variable to something like

```
COUNT(EntityId) AS CASE @@Role 
                      WHEN 2 THEN 'Tickets Processed' 
                      WHEN 3 THEN 'Tickets Reviewed'  
                   END
```

EDIT:

Sample of current result:

```
@@Role = 2 or @@Role = 3
```

Both return:

```
User        Tickets Processed
-----------------------------
Steve       1
Gerald      3
John        1
Paul        2
Peter       5
Total       12
```

Desired result:

```
@@Role = 2 

User        Tickets Processed
-----------------------------
Steve       1
Gerald      3
John        1
Paul        2
Peter       5
Total       12

@@Role = 3

User        Tickets Reviewed
-----------------------------
Steve       1
Gerald      3
John        1
Paul        2
Peter       5
Total       12
```

Sample data

```
EntityID    Processor   Reviewer
----------------------------------
1           Peter       Bob
2           Peter       Paul
3           Peter       Bob
4           John        Paul
5           Peter       Bob
6           Peter       Bob
...
```

Comment: I feel like using dynamic sql would be perfect for this

Comment: Some sample data with your expected result would helpful to determine if a pivot would do the trick. Otherwise you might be looking at a stored proc with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: No, you cannot do what you want with a simple `select`.  The columns returned by a query have well-defined names.  You would need dynamic SQL to do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use dynamic sql, or you can split the logic based on the `@@role` variable:

```
IF @@Role = 2 THEN {do Query A}
ELSE {do Query B}
```

But you definitely cannot base the column alias on the value of a variable in the context of a non-dynamic query.

Comment: Alright, thanks, that's what I thought, but I was hoping it wouldn't be so.